# ls command without username?

Tags: command-line, ls

I want to use `ls --full-time -lnG` but do not wish to list the user names at all. Is there any way to do this?

I would consider `-n` and `-G` optional if it is conflicting with getting this done.

Comment: You mean don't list user id-s, right? As your original command won't list usernames too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the man page of `ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

> -g     like -l, but do not list owner

This would prevent the owner name from being listed. So what you intend to do is probably this:

```
ls --full-time -Gg
```

---

Also if you would like to see only a few desired columns, do `ls -l` and choose the columns using this:

```
ls -l | awk {'print $column_no'}
```

For example, if you only want the filename and size, do this:

```
ls -l | awk {'print $5" "$9'}
```

---

<sub>Source:</sub>

- [Formatting output of ls](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/formatting-output-of-ls-193418/)

Answer (score 4):

Easy way: from `man ls`

> ```
> -g     like -l, but do not list owner
> ```

So

```
ls --full-time -gnG
```

should work.

Geeky++ way: (need formatting but it's just to give the idea... and it's really adaptable):

```
ls --full-time -lnG | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) if (i!=3) printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NR) ? "\n" : OFS)}'
```